# rspec-core is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

When I run `rspec spec` I get this error:

```
bundle exec rspec spec/models/spree_user_spec.rb
/Users/martins/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@solidus/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:304:in `block in replace_gem': rspec-core is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile. (Gem::LoadError)
        from /Users/martins/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@solidus/bin/rspec:22:in `<main>'
        from /Users/martins/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@solidus/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
        from /Users/martins/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@solidus/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Any idea why? Here you got my Gemfile:

**Gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby '2.2.3'

gem 'solidus'

gem 'quiet_assets', group: :development

gem 'dotenv-rails', groups: [:development, :test]

gem 'puma'

gem 'cancancan', '~> 1.10'

group :test do
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '~> 4.5.0'
  gem 'capybara', '~> 2.4'
  gem 'capybara-screenshot'
  gem 'database_cleaner', '~> 1.3'
  gem 'email_spec'
  gem 'launchy'
  gem 'rspec-activemodel-mocks', '~>1.0.2'
  gem 'rspec-collection_matchers'
  gem 'rspec-its'
  gem 'rspec-core'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.3.0'
  gem 'simplecov'
  gem 'webmock', '1.8.11'
  gem 'poltergeist'
  gem 'timecop'
  gem 'with_model'
  gem 'rspec_junit_formatter'
end

gem 'rails', '4.2.5'
gem 'pg', '~> 0.15'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'

gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc




group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug'
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  gem 'spring'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'rubocop'
  gem 'spring-commands-rspec'
  gem 'guard-rspec', require: false
end

group :darwin, :test do
  gem 'rb-fsevent'
end

group :production do
  gem 'exception_notification'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rspec-core` is a runtime dependency for `rspec-rails` and so you should not need to explicitly add it to your Gemfile.  Did you add it as a result of trying to debug this? See the docs [here](https://rubygems.org/gems/rspec-rails/versions/3.3.3).

When you run `bundle install`, bundler will go out and retrieve necessary dependencies and include those in your Gemfile.lock, with the specific versions required to support your Gemfile gems.

I recommend you start by removing `rspec-core` from your `Gemfile` and running `bundle install`.  Then take a look at your `Gemfile.lock`.  Is rspec-core in there? It should be. If not, it would help if you paste the snippet of your lock file that contains `rspec-rails` and its dependencies?

Comment: You're right. I added `rspec-core` when the error message said I was missing it. Removed it from Gemfile, ran `bundle`. It's present in `Gemfile.lock`

Comment: The strange thing is that this branch of my project works when running at an other Mac. I think there is some environment settings that has been messed up.

Comment: Interesting.  Does `rake spec` work? Does `bundle show` list the rspec gem?

Answer (score 5):

A similar problem led me here, except in addition to `rspec-core`, none of the gems in my `test` group were installed, because apparently bundler remembers your initial switches.

Updating `.bundle/config` to not include `BUNDLE_WITHOUT: "test"` let `bundle install` add the correct gems.